# Bootstrap ADF Test

Tags: r, bootstrap, augmented-dickey-fuller

I'm interested into the application of bootstrapping for the case of smaller data sets. I tried following reproducible script to compare the results of a "normal" ADF test with a "bootstrapped" test.

```
library(vars)
library(boot)
data(Canada)
Canada <- data.frame(Canada)

# Standard ADF test
summary(ur.df(Canada["prod"][,1], type = "trend", lags=4, selectlags = "AIC")) # non-stationary

# Bootstrap Test
# Function to obtain test statistics
tstat <- function(x) {
  adf <- ur.df(x, type = "drift", lags=12, selectlags = "AIC")@teststat[1]
  return(adf)
} 

# Test
tstat(Canada["prod"][,1])

# Bootstrapping with 100 replications 
results <- boot(tstat(Canada["prod"][,1]), statistic=tstat, R=100)

# View results
results

# 95% confidence interval 
boot.ci(results)
```

However, the script returns an error:

```
> results <- boot(tstat(Canada["prod"][,1]), statistic=tstat, R=100)
Error in statistic(data, original, ...) : unused argument (original)
```

**Questions:**

1. Does it make sense to bootstrap the test? I aspire to do the same with a wald.test.
2. Can you resolve the error?

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two issues with your implementation.

From `?boot`:

```
boot(data, statistic, etc.)
```

where

```
data
```

The **data** as a vector, matrix or data frame.

```
statistic
```

A function which when applied to data returns a vector containing the statistic(s) of interest. [...] In all other cases statistic must take at least two arguments. The first argument passed will always be the original data. **The second will be a vector of indices**, frequencies or weights which define the bootstrap sample. [...]

First, what you pass on in the first argument is the test statistic, not the series. Second, your function lacks a second argument specifying the indices.

Something like this runs:

```
# Function to obtain test statistics
tstat <- function(x,i) {
  adf <- ur.df(x[i], type = "drift", lags=12, selectlags = "AIC")@teststat[1]
  return(adf)
} 
# Bootstrapping with 100 replications 
results <- boot(Canada["prod"][,1], statistic=tstat, R=100)
```

Still, I **do not** recommend to actually use this code as bootstrapping unit root tests requires care. Please perform a search for something like "bootstrap unit root tests" to see how correct algorithms for bootstrap unit root tests might look like. It is not to be expected that `boot` performs such algorithms.